# what if data edit at same time in sql server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, ado.net

Lets say, I have one table and 2 seperate users enter data to same row in same time, and that table has limit just for one record.

So how sql server choose and accept which users edit?

What is the best way to protect this?

Comment: "and that table has limit just for one record" - what do you mean by this? By default, SQL server will let the last user win. If you don't want this approach I would suggest you look into optimistic concurrency.

Comment: It can be found in transaction log. But, you cat modify your table which can keep the user identifier as well.

Comment: SQL has locks to prevent this.  You can better protect this by using an `Update Table With (RowLock)` hint.  But, generally speaking, it will go to whomever did it last.

Comment: You can start by learning about ACID properties of databases (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID).  Then you can review the documentation for SQL Server on locking and transactions.

Comment: Unless you have thought about this and provided ways to prevent it, the last user's data will be stored over top of the previous user's data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To protect against two users updating a record at the same time, you could have a last_updated field in the table whose records you're looking to update.  This field, on each row update will be automatically update to the current timestamp; that way the second user's attempt to update can be invalidated, if we choose.

For example:

**Table1:**

*Note that the last_updated field is set to ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP*

```
+------------------------------------+
| id | some_data |   last_updated    |
+------------------------------------+
|  1 |"Some text"|2014-06-09 14:00:00|
|  2 | "example" |2014-06-09 15:00:00|
+------------------------------------+
```

Lets assume we're using a form as our interface to update record 1 on two client machines at the same time.  We've done a SELECT statement and filled the form with the content from record #1, if we take the last_updated timestamp and store that on the client side while the user is modifying data, we can build a query that looks like the following to help protect against an accidental overwrite:

```
UPDATE Table1
SET some_data = '<<your data>>'
WHERE last_updated = '<<stored timestamp>>' AND
id = 1
LIMIT 1;
```

So with a query like this, client #1 is going to execute this query with the correct timestamp, resulting in a successful update.  Client #2 is now going to attempt to update, but have an invalid timestamp as the last_updated field has been updated.  At this point we can notify the user that their update attempt was a failure and say that it could be because that record was in use, it's really up to you.

That's just one method of achieving something like what you've described, I hope that helps.  I'm sure there are better ways but this was the best I could come up with right now.

Good luck!